# Can't get the code right for Struts2 form validation using expression language

Tags: jsp, struts2, el

I want struts2 form validation using expression language.
I have tried but the EL is displaying no message.

Here is my code for **login.jsp** :

```
<s:form action="login" method="post">
    ${requestScope.invid}
    <s:textfield name="user" label="Username"/>
    ${requestScope.invpass}
    <s:password name="pass" label="Password" />
    <s:submit value="Log In" />
</s:form>
```

Here is my code for **loginaction.java** :

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport
{
private String user,pass;
HttpServletRequest request;

//setters and getters
public String execute()
{
    try
    {
        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Hfslogin l2=(Hfslogin)s.get(Hfslogin.class,user);
        if(l2!=null)
        {
            if(l2.getPass().equals(pass))
            {
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                request.setAttribute("invpass","Password does not     match for this ID");
                return "relogin";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("invid","ID not registered");
            return "relogin";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "relogin";
    }
}
}
```

Here is my **struts.xml** code :

```
<action name="login" class="com.signin.LoginAction">
        <result name="relogin">login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Do you have any exception?

Comment: No exceptions . Its just not working

Comment: Sure but nobody can help you because it requires knowledge of Java. But you don't have a [tag:java] on the question.

Comment: Okk, am adding it then..

Comment: S2 has validation feature. Use it, instead of hacking your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer while I was re-checking again.
I had not implemented ServletRequestAware interface because of which my 'request' variable was acting as null. ServletRequestAware implements the abstract method which initializes the request.